# Docker: copy contents from subdirectories not working

Tags: docker

I have a very strange issue with copying the contents of subdirectories to a Docker container.
This is the directory structure:

[image]

Note: There are two Dockerfiles, I use the one on the upper level for test purposes. Ignore the one in the WebApp folder.

I want to copy the directories Bilder and JSON to the container, including all contents, but it doesn't work. The folders in the container will be empty. However, copying the Testdir does indeed work.

This is part of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-buster

# -- Init --
RUN mkdir -p  /app/src
WORKDIR /app/src

ADD WebApp/Testdir ./Testdir #works
ADD WebApp/Bilder ./Bilder #doesn't work

CMD ["sleep", "50"] #to check contents
```

I build the image as part of a docker-compose.yml file with
`docker-compose build test`

Does anyone have a clue what's happening here? I've been searching for a solution for quite some time...

Comment: Are you sure about that TestDir? Isn't it already in docker? Well src paths are interpreted as relative to the source of the context of the build. So your paths should look like 
`ADD Bilder ./Bilder`

Comment: Where are the `Dockerfile` ? From which path you launch the command ? Which `docker build` command you launch ?

Comment: Oh yes, this was confusing, I added two remarks on that in the question.

Comment: @Stimmot - Not sure if you are still stuck on this problem, but could you also add the relevant service config from the docker-compose? There might be something in the build config of the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested by why this was a problem: it actually had nothing to do with Docker. I was working on a cluster that was not synchronizing my local files to the server correctly, so I solved this issue by checking every time whether the files were actually copied from my local machine to the cluster. Just in case someone has a similar issue, you might be advised to check whether the file accessibility could be the problem.